# Time Zone auto update not working in android

Tags: android, android-source, bsp

I'm working in aosp based project in a device with android interface. The auto timezone option is enabled in the settings but when the system is booted the time zone is always in GMT but I'm in India, the timezone should be GMT+5:30. I don't know which file in the source has the problem

Comment: Even if you set it in Settings, it may be pulling the time-zone setting from somewhere else while it is being compiled.  Or may be set in Vendor Android.mk. You can look here : https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/timezone-rules

Comment: Timezone auto-update is done using NITZ protocol AFAIK.
I think your device needs to have a cellular connection in order to get that information form cellular towers.

Alternativly you can add something custom to figure it out via IP geolocation

Comment: I have solved the issue, by adding IcheneaNLP apk to packages/apps
Thanks for your comments